# Django: how can I put url() as a guaranteed last element of `urlpatterns` list?

Tags: python, django, reactjs, react-router

I have a web app (django for backend, reactjs for frontend) with `urlpatterns`:

```
urlpatterns = [

# API Notifications
url(r'^api/notification/v0/', include(notification_router.urls)),
url(r'^api/notification/v0/mark_all_as_read/$', mark_all_as_read),
url(r'^api/notification/v0/unread_count/$',
    unread_count),

# etc 
]
```

Next, because this is react app, I set url pattern to catch and redirect all request (exclude useful) to root template with react router:

```
urlpatterns += url(r'', cache_page(settings.PAGE_CACHE_SECONDS)(RootView.as_view()), name='customer-root'),
```

And on local server it pretty work.

BUT, when I try to deploy this app, few another processes (`collectstatic`, for example) change `urlpatterns` and add new urls to the end of `urlpatterns` list (after `customer-root` url).

So, instead static files (css / js / etc) client get html code of `customer-root` view template.

Question is: how can I put my `customer-root` url pattern as a guaranteed last element of `urlpatterns` list? Even if another process will change `urlpatterns` at deploy time.

Comment: What do you mean “another process will change urlpatterns”? No one changes the urlpatterns during deploy.

Comment: Custom STATICFILES_STORAGE setting will add `staticfiles_urlpatterns()` to the end of `urlpatterns`

Comment: I'm talking about pool runtime vars, not about physical changing source code

Comment: Ah. Try `r'^$'`